# How to resolve web service url in JQuery Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a ASP.Net project(not website). I have added the JQuery autocomplete widget to my master page and use the widget in MyPage.aspx.

In the .master I use something like this:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "/MyService.asmx/MySearchMethod",
                    data: "{ 'param1': '" + request.term + "' }",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
```

The MyService.asmx points to:

```
  CodeBehind="~/App_Code/MyServiceMethods.cs" Class="MySearchMethod"
```

Everything works fine while in VS2010 development.

The problem is when I deploy the app to a test web server, I get the below error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No web service found at: /MyService.asmx
```

How can I reference my web service in the ajax url: so that the address can be resolved when the app is deployed?

Comment: Did you try going into your browser and trying to ping the service from js in your console? usually this is the best way to figure out what is going on, not working in your environment so can't tell you exactly what is going on, could be a lot of things

Comment: When you deploy, are you deploying to a website that maps to the root of a domain (e.g., http://example.com), or to a sub-app/dir of an existing website (e.g., http://example.com/myapp)?

Comment: The string you are passing to data is not JSON. Don't try to create JSON by hand, use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: I am deploying to a sub directory. I deploy to "MyDomain.Com/MyAppDir/"  MyAppDir will contain the deploy files. Do I have to resolve the .asmx path somehow before setting it in the Ajax url property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use it as follows:

```js
$.ajax({
                    url: "MyService.asmx/MySearchMethod",
                    data: "{ 'param1': '" + request.term + "' }",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
```

or:

```js
$.ajax({
                    url: "~/MyService.asmx/MySearchMethod",
                    data: "{ 'param1': '" + request.term + "' }",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
```

Comment: I thought I tried all combination of the url: property. But the first one did it, no slash in front url: "MyService.asmx/MySearchMethod"